# Can't draw a line in open cv 3.xx

Tags: c++, opencv, line

I want to try to draw a line. But it always stop working and shows the dialog box (continue or break).

Here my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namedWindow("rute", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Mat rute;
    line(rute, Point(0, 120), Point(320, 120), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, CV_AA);
    imshow("rute", rute);
}
```

The error that I get:
opencv error: assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)

I use Open CV 3.2 in c++. visual studio 2015.
Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Your `rute` matrix has 0 width and 0 height, since you never properly initialized it.

Comment: Also an [`imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#imshow) without [`waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey). Read the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your matrix.
Here an example of draw line which works:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
  cv::Mat r(640, 480, CV_8UC3);
  cv::line(r, cv::Point(0, 120), cv::Point(320, 120), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
  cv::imshow("rute", r);
  cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: it draw the line in my case. maybe change the values.

Comment: I removed some noise in the code... hope you don't mind

Comment: Yeah I saw. Thank you !

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! it works properly. I just forget to add waitKey. Thanks a lot for your help!